# How to correctly import IronPython into Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ironpython

What is the correct way to import IronPython into unity?

When i just put the Lib and netstandard2.0 folders into `Assets/Plugins/IronPython` it gives me these errors:

```
Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/IronPython/netstandard2.0/IronPython.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'System.CodeDom'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Mono.Posix.NETStandard'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/IronPython/netstandard2.0/IronPython.Modules.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'Mono.Posix.NETStandard'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/IronPython/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Dynamic.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'System.CodeDom'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/IronPython/netstandard2.0/DLLs/IronPython.SQLite.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Reference has errors 'IronPython'.

Assembly 'Assets/Plugins/IronPython/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Scripting.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'System.CodeDom'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
Unable to resolve reference 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.
```

I am using Unity 2019.3.7f1.
I have .NET standard 2.0 selected as my compatibility level and Mono as my backend.
I have downloaded the latest release of IronPython from the GitHub repo.

What am i doing wrong and what is the correct way to import it into Unity?

> ### EDIT:
>
> Changed backend from IL2CPP to Mono, which fixed the `Microsoft.Scripting` reference error, however it did not fix other references.

Comment: You have a guide to help you. See https://mikalikes.men/use-python-with-unity-3d-the-definitive-guide/

and you have even an unity package see  https://mikakalevi.com/downloads/python_for_unity.unitypackage

Comment: @Frenchy Can you explain how to import external libraries? I've been trying to make numpy and opencv work (using 2.7 compatible version), but I keep failing.

Comment: @GrantAllan, install an external library into ironpython is another problem and you can do that only if the library is compatible with .net...  so by default its not ..so for numpy maybe look https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET    and search the same thing for opencv